# How to Append a constantly changing value to a list?

Tags: python

I am quite new to the python coding scene and is currently working on a code on Python using a ultrasonic sensor, I want to add the output value into a list (maintaining the list size)where the list is constantly updating with the latest value from the ultrasonic sensor basically OVERWRITTING the list in a sense,

I have seen examples of Append but they are from fix values,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> a + b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

is there anyway to append with the output from the ultrasonic sensor? Thank you very much

```
my_list=[100,50,10,20,30,50] #current list

#example of expected output
distance=300
distance=250
distance=230

my_list=[230,250,300,100,50,10]  
# the latest 3 reading will be appended to the front of the list 
# while still maintaining the size of my_list
```

Do let let me know if further clarification or information is needed, thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Comment: hi, I updated my question for a clearer explanation, the page has given me a deeper explanation for append and extend and the differences but I do not think it solves my question, thank you for suggestion

Comment: Do you always want to maintain the same size for the list and append to the front? Because in the example it seems like you append to the front and maintain the same size for the list.

Comment: Yes, That's exactly it, the same size list and just append it to the front basically overwriting the list in a way, sorry if it was unclear before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every value, you can use `my_list.insert(0, new_value)` which will insert new value to 1st position. Your code will look something like:

```
    my_list.insert(0, new_distance) # add new value to beginning (0 index)
    my_list = my_list[:-1] # remove last element to keep the size same
```

You can also combine those, eg: `my_list[:-1].insert(0, new_distance)`

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list.append(distance)
```

.append() is a built in function in lists.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
distance = 300
distance = 250
distance = 230
my_list = [230, 250, 300, 100, 50, 10]
my_list.append(20)
print(my_list)
```

this will append 20 to the list and the result is `[230, 250, 300, 100, 50, 10, 20]`

and if you like to append it to a certain position of your list, then use insert

```
distance = 300
distance = 250
distance = 230
my_list = [230, 250, 300, 100, 50, 10]
my_list.insert(0, 20) # 0 is the position and 20 is what to append
print(my_list)
```

at this code, 0 is the position and 20 is what to append. you can change the value

After reading your question carefully this is the code:

```
my_list=[100,50,10,20,30,50] #current list
threelist = []
for _ in range(4):
    distance=300 # your senser value
    threelist.append(distance)
while len(threelist) > 3: 
    del threelist[0]
my_list = threelist + my_list
while len(my_list) > 6:
    del my_list[-1]
print(my_list)
```

this code appends distance to threelist then `+` it to the my_list. and `del` the last 3 value.
and you can change `distance=300` to your senser value.
I hope this helped you.

Comment: ah yes, but the currently the distance is the value coming in from the ultrasonic sensor and it is constantly updating, so appending a fix value is not my goal but very useful to know,thank you.

Comment: @yongjie I don't know it's the right answer for you  but I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah i see, yes you are right that the value is constantly changing, but does not exactly solve my problem but does help me understand how the append works, I have also updated my question, maybe that will provide a clearer explanation? Regardless, I appreciate your help, Tysm

Comment: @yongjie I edited my answer. and thanks for giving update for your question

Answer (score 1):

You can append to the front with the insert function

`my_list.insert(0, distance)`

and delete last element with

`del my_list[-1]`

Here I am assuming you are getting sensor data within a loop one at a time.